# The best way to implement window close event

Tags: javascript, vb.net

Long story is short - I am trying to submit a certain form when user closes the window, or is not responding for 20min.

The second I've done using this code:

```
timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
    submitThisForm(document.forms.sendDealerInfo);
    console.log("Timed out...");
}, 600000);
```

For the first one I've tried with this code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    submitThisForm(document.forms.sendDealerInfo);
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    return null;
}
```

Unfortunately `window.onbeforeunload` event won't trigger in all browsers (in Chrome and Opera for example).
I also tried: `$(window).unload(function () {...` and `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {...`
But same story - they won't work in all browsers.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do some other way? Perhaps with sessions?

Answer (score 1):

As Suman says, `onBeforeUnload` is supported in all the major browsers. But most, if not all, the browsers will not let you do anything within that event beyond returning a string for the "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" dialog.

Then with `onUnload` you're attempting to submit a form after the page has already been unloaded, and navigation is already happening. It would be a very odd user experience to be navigating away then be redirected somewhere else.

Trying to submit a form when the window is closed isn't a very safe method. The web browser could crash, the user could force close it, the internet connection could be interrupted, among other things. I think your best bet would be to submit the form every so often. Possibly detecting an idle timeout of a few seconds, then submitting your form?

Answer (score 0):

`window.onbeforeunload` is works in all major browsers, Like it is supported from **Chrome 1** and **Opera 12**

[Browser Compability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload)

Comment: You gave me a link for `onunload` not for `onbeforeunload`.

Comment: have you tried to disaply the dialouge box for confirming that your `onbeforeunload` with removing other codes.

Comment: just put this code first `window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};` and test in chrome.